# Why did python-3.x remove ROT-13 as an encoding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, encoding, rot13

With python-2.7, you can pretty easily implement a rot-13 Ceasar Cipher using

```
>>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.encode('rot-13')
'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm'
```

You'll even find it in the [Zen of Python code in the CPython repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d310f13cd2c321f0cca8429f611546c7888ae561/Lib/this.py).

However, the same code on python3.6 gives -

```
>>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.encode('rot-13')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: 'rot-13' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

If I want to use the `rot-13` encoding in python3.x, I'll need to import `codecs`.

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.encode('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'rot-13')
'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm'
```

Of course, this is really a minor issue, I don't mind importing `codecs` to implement a caesar cipher (it's a builtin anyway). I'm just curious to know if there was any underlying rationale behind this design decision. Maybe the reason is as simple as "rot-13 isn't really an encoding", I don't know.

If someone can shed some light on this, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Check out [#10807](https://bugs.python.org/issue10807) and [#7475](https://bugs.python.org/issue7475) and [the commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b6f424043d267eac9c870d9991a6453a821ff81d) in which they were removed. This may reveal some insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can also take a look at this [page](https://bugs.python.org/issue21171) where someone flagged your issue as a bug. 
For those who don't want to go through the site and its followup links, the simple response from a python committer was as follows:

"Since rot_13 is a transcoder, not an encoder, the error message is correct, as is the fix for the function. However, since neither the module encodings.rot_13 nor the rot13 function in the module are documented, (not even in 2.7), I wonder if the function and the if __name__; clause are ancient holdovers that should be removed."

Comment: see also [#10807](https://bugs.python.org/issue10807) and [#7475](https://bugs.python.org/issue7475) and [the commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b6f424043d267eac9c870d9991a6453a821ff81d) in which they were removed.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search for "what's new in python rot-13" turns up this: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#codec-handling-improvements

> In Python 3.4, the interpreter is able to identify the known non-text
>   encodings provided in the standard library and direct users towards
>   these general purpose convenience functions when appropriate:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> b"abcdef".decode("hex")
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.decode() to handle arbitrary codecs
>
> >>> "hello".encode("rot13")
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> LookupError: 'rot13' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
> ```

So apparently, this was a cleanup operation to separate actual text encodings (which you would use in an `open(file, encoding="foo")`call) from other encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Python moved the rot13 to (as you said), codecs. My guess is to better reflect what rot13 is and to use a different and more general interface. As TimPietzcker said, most likely cleanup and trying to group similar functions.

Comment: Sorry - but if you "guess" and quote Tim Pietzcker and the person who asked the question - you are only parroting others answers. What new facts did warrant "your" answer?

Comment: From https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html, as I mentioned: It moved to implement this interface, and to better represent what rot13 does,  namely encode text to text.

Comment: Also, all answers so far have not been facts, but speculation.